# Docker for Windows - Export Volume Data

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-for-windows

I created two docker containers with compose on Docker for Windows, using `wordpress` and `mariadb`. I've created a volume for wordpress that points to my PC's normal filesystem, but mariaDB's is still contained within the Hyper-V's Virtual Hard Disk.

The mount point is at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/1995...ca3/_data`
I've tried looking at previous answers, but the link that would explain how to backup, copy, or restore volumes [redirects to a general volume explanation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes). Most plugins or scripts I've seen for Docker typically refers to a *nix environment.

Would anyone know of a modern method to export and import volumes mounted to Linux containers in Docker for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The way I normally do this is to start a container that mounts two volumes, the `source` volume and the `destination` volume, and I run a command in that container that copies the contents of one volume to another. I don't have a copy of windows at hand to find out how to copy all files recursively, but I'm sure it can do it quite easily.

Comment: I believe this may be helpful in the long run for others. I've done something similar with `mysqldump`. Do you have a command to copy volume contents regardless of the specified container? Even a *nix-based one can perhaps be translated to windows.